# why is return used within if statement in this java code?

Tags: java

so here is the code :
i fully understand the code but i am confused why return is used and i do know what return keyword does .
i tried running the code without using return but the result was same

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int day, num1, num2;
        System.out.println("* * * * * * * * * * * *" +"\n" + "1. For addition" +"\n" + "2. For Subtraction" +"\n" + "3. For multipication" +"\n" + "4. For division" +"\n" +"* * * * * * * * * * * *");
        System.out.println("Please enter your 1st num");
        num1= sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter your 2nd num");
        num2= sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter your choice");
        day= sc.nextInt();
        if(day==4 && num2==0) {
            System.out.println("0 is not valid");
            return;
        };
        switch(day) {
            case 1: System.out.println(num1+num2);break;
            case 2: System.out.println(num1-num2);break;
            case 3: System.out.println(num1*num2);break;
            case 4: System.out.println(num1/num2);break;
            default : System.out.println("Wrong input");break;
        }
    }
}
```

Why is `return` used at the if condition line ?

Comment: To exit the function early

Comment: what will happen if we don't use return at that line ?

Comment: If you didn't have the return there based on the conditions day==4 && num2==0 you have a divide by zero condition for case:4

Comment: It will continue on to the switch case...

Comment: it will continue, but why dont you try it and see what results you get? use the debugger for this to see what exactly is happening with your code.

Comment: Should this have been closed - the OP doesn't seem to be asking what the `return` keyword does, but rather why the method returns on that condition?

Comment: Agree with commenter, this is not asking what return is used for in a condition but why was it placed there.

Comment: i was confused why return was used and was not asking what return does
thanks
it is clear now

Answer (score 1):

If you read the `println`, it says "0 is not valid". I am assuming (and you should as well) that the rest of the code cannot run given the input, so the `return` statement exits the program before it fails.

Answer (score 1):

`return` statement from a void method will terminate the method and in this case, when you call it in `public static void main` it terminates the whole application.

Your code has a validity check and when the validation fails, your application writes an error message and quits.